# Setting headers in websphere portal

Tags: websphere-portal

I am new to websphere portal.

How to set headers in websphere portlet 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling two-phase rendering: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev-portlet/jsr2phase_overview.html.

Enable two-phase rendering in the portlet.xml like this:

```
<portlet>
    ...
    <container-runtime-option>
        <name>javax.portlet.renderHeaders</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </container-runtime-option>
</portlet>
```

Then you can set the headers within the doHeaders method by using the setProperty or addProperty response methods:

```
@Override
protected void doHeaders(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
   response.addProperty("MyHeader", "MyHeaderValue");
}
```